# How to parse KafkaFlow message using a custom serializer

Tags: c#, jsonserializer, kafkaflow

KafkaFlow serialises like this

```json
{
    "actions": {
        "$type": "Full.ActionTypeName, supplying-assembly-name",
        "$values": [
            {
                "propname": "propvalue" //properties of ActionTypeName instance
            }
        ]
    },
    "resources": {
        "$type": "Full.ResourceTypeName, supplying-assembly-name",
        "$values": [
            {
                "propname": "propvalue" //properties of ResourceTypeName instance
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

With the following classes

```cs
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

public class FlowMessage
{
    public FlowType Actions { get; set; }
    public FlowType Resources { get; set; }
}

public class FlowType
{
    [JsonPropertyName("$type")]
    public string TypeDescriptor { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("$values")]
    public JsonElement[] Values { get; set; }
    public string TypeName() => TypeDescriptor.Split(",")[0];
    public Type Type() => System.Type.GetType(TypeName());
}
```

I can get this to parse.

```cs
var stream = File.Open("sample.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
JsonSerializerOptions seropt = new()
{
    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
    Converters = { new JsonStringEnumConverter() }
};

var foo = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(stream, typeof(FlowMessage), seropt);
```

This "FlowType" notation is used recursively to represent object graphs. According to the `JsonSerializer` documentation it is possible to [associate a JsonConverter with a type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-7-0#registration-sample---jsonconverter-on-a-type). What I want to do is apply this somehow so that instead of the pair of nodes `$type` and `$values` the serialiser returns an array of objects of appropriate type.

It seems like I need to use the factory pattern converter described on that page, but I need a value from inside the `FlowType` *instance* to determine the target type for the converter that the factory will produce. So I need to parse it first as a `FlowType` and then again using the converter. It's really not obvious how to go about this.

Surely *someone* has built a deserialiser of this sort. I look forward to your advice on how to deal with this.

#### Update

It appears you can trivially clone the reader for the purpose of read-ahead [as described elsewhere in the same document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-7-0#an-alternative-way-to-do-polymorphic-deserialization). But I'm still pretty wobbly so if someone knows what they're doing with this I wouldn't object to being led by the nose.

Answer (score 1):

It appears this format is supported in both directions by `Newtonsoft.Json` if you specify serialisation options as follows.

```cs
JsonSerializerSettings _options = new()
{
  TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto,
};
```

I'd rather not run *two* serialisers so if anyone can figure out how to handle it using `System.Text.Json` I would accept that as the correct answer.